# How to pass poi cell range to dataset of JFreeChart?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jfreechart

I want to pass a cell refernce to my dataset of JFreeChart. How can I pass a cell of excel for chart using JFreeChart?

For example,

```
DefaultCategoryDataset my_bar_chart_dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

my_bar_chart_dataset.addValue("Here i want to pass cell reference","Customer","");
```

I am using [apache-poi](/questions/tagged/apache-poi) library and [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) for chart.

For example,
        we have in excel like i want to drag a cell and create chart like that i have to pass cell reference so that if i can mouse over graph part then that will show me cell which i have selected.

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v30F.png) like what i want attach in image. i have to pass cell reference in jfreechart as i mention in question.

Comment: Once you have the data, follow [`org.jfree.chart.demo.BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html).

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek this question is not duplicate of any question as you mention what i want is diffrent.i have to pass a cell reference in jfreechart addvalue method

Comment: @trashgod please explain how would i pass a cell reference.      DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new        DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataset.addValue(7445, "JFreeSVG", "Warm-up");
        dataset.addValue(24448, "Batik", "Warm-up");
        dataset.addValue(4297, "JFreeSVG", "Test");
        dataset.addValue(21022, "Batik", "Test");
        return dataset;

Comment: @trashgod as per your code i have trided but it will pass value not cellreference

Comment: You'll have to loop though the referenced cells and add the _values_ to the dataset. Then, edit your question to include a [mcve] that focuses on any remaining problem.

Comment: @trashgod that i have already done by loop but i want  to pass a cell reference not value.

Comment: `DefaultCategoryDataset` has no method with that signature; you'll have to create one. If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: @trashgod how can i create method for pass a cell reference. can you give me please some tips for that. and how to edit question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) don't understand what exactly you talking about i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: The [mcve] link explains it.